# Select x random rows based on x number of weights

Tags: php, mysql, probability

I need to generate a list of songs based on their genres. How much of each genre is returned in the list depends on how they are weighted by the user.

So they may set...

```
Rock  -  5 out of 10
Pop   -  2 out of 10
Dance -  1 out of 10
Folk  - 10 out of 10
```

Each track in the database table has a `genre_id`:

```
Rock  = 1
Pop   = 2
Dance = 3
Folk  = 4
```

They can also choose how many tracks to return, so it may be 10, 20... up to 100.

I have 2 tables

```
TRACKS
id (INT)
track_name (VARCHAR)
genre_id (INT)

GENRES
id (INT)
name (VARCHAR)
```

I'm using MySQL and PHP to accomplish this, any help would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works rather well. There will however, in some cases be a rounding error on the total of songs (never more than 1);

```
/*
 * It's more likely to fill the first two arrays from a query, but for 
 * the example I defined them like
 * genreId => value
 */
$genres = array(
    1 => 'rock',
    2 => 'pop',
    3 => 'dance',
    4 => 'folk',
    27 => 'classical'
);

$pointsPerGenre = array(
    1 => 5, //rock, 5 out of 10
    2 => 2, //pop, 2 out of 10
    3 => 1, //etc...
    4 => 10,
    27 => 7
);

$totalPoints  = array_sum($pointsPerGenre);

$numberOfSongs = 20;

$songsPerPoint = $numberOfSongs / $totalPoints;

$songsPerGenre = array();
foreach(array_keys($genres) as $genreId)
{
    $songsPerGenre[$genreId] = round($pointsPerGenre[$genreId] * $songsPerPoint);
}


$queryParts = array();
foreach($songsPerGenre as $genreId => $numberOfSongsPerGenre)
{
    $queryParts[] = "(SELECT * FROM TRACKS WHERE genre_id = $genreId ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $numberOfSongsPerGenre)";
}

$query = implode("\nUNION\n", $queryParts);
```

This will output the following query (where you can see the rounding error, the user receives one bonus song in this case):

```
(SELECT * FROM TRACKS WHERE genre_id = 1 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 4)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TRACKS WHERE genre_id = 2 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TRACKS WHERE genre_id = 3 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TRACKS WHERE genre_id = 4 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 8)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM TRACKS WHERE genre_id = 27 ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help man! It makes sense to me now. I think I'll replace those ORDER BY RAND()'s though with a php rand/limit